# Bash - Diference between echo `basename $HOME` and echo $(basename $HOME)

Tags: bash

Thank you very much in advance for helping.

The title says everything: what's the difference between using:

```
echo `basename $HOME`
```

and

```
echo $(basename $HOME)
```

Please notice that I know what the basename command does, that both syntax are valid and both commands give the same output.

I was just wondering if there is any difference between both and if it's possible, why there are two syntaxes for this.

Cheers

Rafael

Comment: Some people also broke their backtick key answering so questions and can only use the 2nd form...

Comment: Read for differences: [Command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)

Comment: By the way, `basename $HOME` - it sounds like you're trying to get your username? If so, it's probably better to use `$USER` directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second form has different escaping rules making it much easier to nest. e.g.

```
echo $(echo $(basename $HOME))
```

I'll leave working out how to do that with ` as an exercise for the reader, it should prove enlightening.

Answer (score 4):

They are one of the same.
please read [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04).

**EDIT** (from the link):
*Command substitution*

Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command itself. Command substitution occurs when a command is enclosed like this:

```
$(command)
```

or like this using backticks:

```
`command`
```

`Bash` performs the expansion by executing *COMMAND* and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.

```
$ franky ~> echo `date`
Thu Feb 6 10:06:20 CET 2003
```

When the old-style backquoted form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by "$", "`", or "\". The first backticks not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the `$(COMMAND)` form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

Command substitutions may be nested. To nest when using the backquoted form, escape the inner backticks with backslashes.

If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and file name expansion are not performed on the results.

Comment: Could you maybe expand on this answer a bit?  Just in case the link ever goes bad.

Comment: @"Just in case the link ever goes bad": The link is from tldp!

Comment: @anishsane: :) Done so anyway :)

Comment: @anishsane I know the odds of that site going bad are low, but that's not the point.  The point is that having a detailed answer is more-useful than having an answer that just says "click this link and read."

Comment: ^^ Agree, but google will more likely show tldp page than this question & we google more than using SO search ;-) :D

Answer (score 2):

They are alternative syntaxes for command substitution. as @Steve mentions they have different quoting rules and th backticks are harder to nest with. On the other hand they are more portable with older version of bash, and other shells eg csh.

Comment: Are there any shells other than `csh` that don't support `$(...)`?